# Macro to Copy Hyperlink from Another Sheet

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a Macro that I found on this site to copy hyperlinks inserted through the ribbon to a different column in another sheet. However, the macro is only working on the first row.

I added `Do` until because `i = 7 to 1007` was not making it go to the `next`. Now it is timing out and it still doesn't work. I'd just use a function for this but it is giving another user problems in Mac, so I'm trying to get around Mac being difficult.

I should state that some of the rows on the first sheet are blank.

```
Sub SwapIt()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 7
    Do Until i > 1007
        Dim newLink As String
        If Worksheets("Directory").Active = True Then
        newLink = Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address ' Get the old horrible link :)
        Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i), Address:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i) 'turns it to a link
        Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address = newLink 'replace with the new link.
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is driving me crazy.

Yay! I figured it out.  Just a missing range.

```
Sub SwapIt()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 7 To 1007
If Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Value > "" Then
    Dim newLink As String
    If Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
    newLink = Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address 
    Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i), Address:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i) 'turns it to a link
    Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address = newLink '' replace with the new link.
    End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yay! I figured it out.  Just a missing range.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on this question.  However, Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase and it relies on the structure that questions are just questions, and answers are the solutions.  Could you move your solution to an answer?  (You're allowed to answer your own question.)  After two days, you will be able to accept your answer, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed code. I also added an If so if the original link cell was blank it would remove the hyperlink in the new sheet because when you resorted the information the cells that corresponded to blanks on the other sheet still had the old hyperlink from the last time the macro applied.

```
Sub UpdateLinks_Click()
' Copy the hyperlink from Modeling Tracker Sheet and apply it to the Directory

Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 To 1007

If Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Value > "" Then
Dim newLink As String
    If Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
    newLink = Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address ' Get the link from the Modeling Tracker
    Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i), Address:=Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i) 'turns it to a link
    Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address = newLink 'replace it with newLink
    End If
End If
If Worksheets("Modeling Tracker").Range("S" & i).Value = "" Then
Worksheets("Directory").Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks.Delete
End If
Next i
Worksheets("Directory").Range("B7:B1007").Font.Color = vbBlack ' this to is avoid the auto hyperlink format
Worksheets("Directory").Range("B7:B1007").Font.Underline = False ' this is to avoid the auto-hyperlink format
End Sub
```