# Copy a hyperlink from one sheet to multiple other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a workbook with 12 sheets, one for each month named JAN, FEB, etc.

I have a hyperlink in cell B2 of JAN which jumps to cell B200 of JAN. I'd like to copy that hyperlink to all the other sheets but when I do the scope of the hyperlink doesn't change to the new sheet, it still references JAN

So how can I copy a hyperlink from one sheet to another and for the link to reference a location on the new sheet, not the sheet where the link was created

Thanks

Comment: You may find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/904406/macro-to-copy-hyperlink-from-another-sheet) to be useful

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. But after copying, it's just a few clicks to make a correction: Right click - select Edit hyperlink - click on the correct sheet in the dialog - click OK. I submit that if you have more than one or a few links to edit per sheet, it may become a major pain.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks, I've simplified the scenario a bit, there are actually quite a few hyperlinks per sheet so I will try the VBA solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub LocalizeAllHyperlinks()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lnk As Hyperlink
For Each sh In Sheets
    For Each lnk In sh.Hyperlinks
        lnk.SubAddress = "'" & sh.Name & "'!" & Split(lnk.SubAddress, "!")(1)
        ' lnk.TextToDisplay = lnk.SubAddress
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

This sub localizes ALL hyperlinks in a workbook to a worksheets they are posessed without any checks. All hyperlinks besides ones to single cell in current workbook will be damaged!